# NoMethodError: undefined method `type_cast_config_to_integer' for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jrubyonrails

I'm trying to setup my first rails project (JRuby) for mysql on Ubuntu platform. I created the project using 
rails new MyFirstRailsProject -d mysql

Now, while starting the rails server using rails server, i m getting the below error.

```
rails server
/JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
NoMethodError: undefined method `type_cast_config_to_integer' for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:Class
             method_missing at org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1657
                 initialize at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-50.0/lib/arjdbc/abstract/statement_cache.rb:25
                 initialize at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-50.0/lib/arjdbc/mysql/adapter.rb:34
            jdbc_connection at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-50.0/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection_methods.rb:15
           mysql_connection at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-50.0/lib/arjdbc/mysql/connection_methods.rb:76
             new_connection at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315
    checkout_new_connection at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325
          block in checkout at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247
                       loop at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1316
          block in checkout at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242
            mon_synchronize at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/monitor.rb:214
                   checkout at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239
        block in connection at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102
            mon_synchronize at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/monitor.rb:214
                 connection at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101
        retrieve_connection at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410
        retrieve_connection at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171
                 connection at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145
           block in Railtie at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:88
              instance_exec at org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1728
                        run at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30
  block in run_initializers at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55
                       each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1735
           run_initializers at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54
                initialize! at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136
             method_missing at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30
                     <main> at /home/jayvijay/RailsTestProject/MyFirstRailsProject/config/environment.rb:5
                    require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:956
           block in require at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
            load_dependency at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236
                    require at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
            block in (root) at /home/jayvijay/RailsTestProject/MyFirstRailsProject/config.ru:1
              instance_eval at org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1691
                 parse_file at /home/jayvijay/RailsTestProject/MyFirstRailsProject/config.ru:3
                     <eval> at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51
                       eval at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:995
                 parse_file at /home/jayvijay/RailsTestProject/MyFirstRailsProject/config.ru:1
                 parse_file at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40
                        app at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:200
                        app at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46
                wrapped_app at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:304
                      start at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:254
             block in start at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70
                        tap at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1765
                     <main> at /JRuby-9.1.17/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55
                    require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:956
                     <main> at script/rails:6
```

I don't know where i am going wrong. 
Below is my database.yml file

```
# MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
#
# Install the MySQL driver:
#   gem install activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: #MyFirstRailsProject_development
  username: username
  password: password
  host: localhost
  port : 3306
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: #MyFirstRailsProject_test
  username: username
  password: password
  host: localhost
  port : 3306
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8    
  database: #MyFirstRailsProject_production
  username: username
  password: password
  host: localhost
  port : 3306
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysql

My SQL Version is:
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.61
```

JRuby Version:

```
jruby 9.1.17.0 (2.3.3) 2018-04-20 d8b1ff9
```

Rails Version

```
Rails 3.2.13
```

Gem File:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter'

gem 'jruby-openssl'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyrhino'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Please can anyone advise, what i am doing wrong here ?
It's JRuby not Ruby -> (well, will that make a difference?)

Comment: Is the database already available, in database.yml i don't see the name

Comment: no, i haven't created the database yet. Is that causing the issue ?

Comment: created the database, but still it throws the same error.

Comment: update the database name in database.yml with proper username and password. follow any blog to setup your first application for clarity

Comment: updated the database in database.yml with correct details, still getting the same error

Comment: No, not working still

Comment: Can you try adding `wait_timeout: 900` to your `database.yml` ?

Comment: not working, same error

Comment: Note that i am using JRuby and not Ruby

Comment: HINT: if it's your first project and you are sure you want to use JRuby instead of MRI, at least try to use the newest version of rails and other gems (currently you are on rails 3.2, newest are 5.2). This update might solve your problems. Also, right now PostgreSQL is a better choice than MySQL.

Comment: its working now, thanks